# How can I print the payload received with ncat?

Tags: linux, udp, netcat

I'm creating an UDP server with the following command:

```
ncat -ulk -p 3333 -c "echo asd" -vv
```

It does receive connections and answers to them correctly, but it doesn't print the UDP payload that comes in the client's message.

The client I'm using is an OpenBSD netcat:

```
$nc -h
OpenBSD netcat (Debian patchlevel 1.206-1ubuntu1)
$echo qwe | nc -u 10.42.0.1 3333 -v
```

Being `10.42.0.1` the IP address of my laptop's wireless interface.

How can I print it?

Comment: would you let me know the client you are using to connect to the UDP port 3333?

Comment: If you use `socat` instead of `ncat` (`socat -v udp6-listen:3333,fork exec:"echo asd"`), you will see the UDP payload printed to the console.